# Character Encoding - RequestDispatcher

Tags: jsp, servlets, character-encoding

I have a servlet and I use

```
String error = "error";
request.setAttribute("loginError", error);
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and I use

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-9"%>
```

in my jsp page, also

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But if I forward a page, this pages' encoding does not work. How can I handle this encoding? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using two different encodings?

Comment: I tried both `UTF-8` and `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`, still same result.

Comment: It will only work when you have same encoding *everywhere*. Using different encodings is absurd and is obviously not going to work so don't do that.

Comment: I tried it to, still the same problem...

Comment: @Mikael What characters are you trying to show and where do they come from? And what do you see on your page in place of them?

Comment: @Esailija They are Turkish characters. When the page is forwarded, ? appears instead of them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i found your unanswered question.
I solved it with adding

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```