# Why UTF-8 does not work in html page when using RequestDispatcher? How to fix it?

Tags: java, html, servlets, encoding, utf-8

I have a page, and UTF-8 works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>:(</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="text-center" style="padding:50px 0">
            <div class="logo">Usuário ou email indisponíveis :(.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nevertheless, when I redirect the user to this resource using RequestDispatcher, it completely **ignores** the UTF-8 encoding of the page (The message is in Portuguese, it displays "UsuÃ¡rio ou email indisponÃ­veis :(.").

```
if (this.hasRecord(connection, (String) requestData.get("reg_username"), (String) requestData.get("reg_email")) == true) {
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/user_taken.html");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
} else {
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

And before anything, I did:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    ...
}
```

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112030/character-encoding-requestdispatcher) is unanswered.

EDIT: I've already changed to response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") instead of request, and the problem persists.

Comment: Can you check the encoding in the server headers, either from the command line with `curl -I http://server/path`, or via the web developper tools / web inspector. by the way your code is setting the request encoding instead of the response one.

Comment: You've just set the character encoding of request body, not of response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction, your problem was on redirect, you could check some solutions [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding), especially the one mentionning the use of [SetCharacterEncodingFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3).

By modifying you `web.xml` in the `web-app` section

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>CharSet<filter-name> 
    <filter-class>filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>encoding</param-name> 
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</filter>
```

You should also add a filter mapping to specify where the it should be applied

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharSet</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I've changed, and the problem persists. RequestDispatcher ignores encoding. It seems to be a bug (Everywhere it has no solution).

Comment: Sorry modified the answe, to suit your issue, the code has no influence on the redirected destionation encoding, more like a server/web-app configuration issue

Comment: Inside "webapps" folder inside "apache-tomcat-8.0.24", there are three folders that contain a folder "WEB-INF" with a "web.xml" inside of it: "ROOT", "host-manager" and "manager". I've included your snippet in all of them, and the problem persists (In the case of the "manager" one, Tomcat was not building the app anymore).

Comment: It should be the web.xml of your own web application

Comment: I've finally solved the problem, and I've added an additional answer explaining what was missing. Thank you VERY much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After days of suffering, I've finally solved the problem.

First of all, I'm new to Tomcat and Web Development in Java, so I had no idea of what "web.xml" file to modify with the answer of dvhh (I've checked and Tomcat has the EXACT filter by default inside the WEB-INF folder inside the host-manager folder). Then, he said I had to change inside my own web application, but there was no web.xml (So I realized I had to create one). I've discovered it's possible to create it in Netbeans and add filters with the GUI quite easily, so I did it (Also, I've removed the `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` from my servlet source).

Still, the problem was still there. Then I've just realized the obvious: "It's running ON JAVA", so I pressed CTR + 5 to open Services in Netbeans, went to Servers, right-clicked Apache Tomcat, selected Properties, went to the Platform and added to the VM Options: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Also, the web app could not be deployed just with `filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter` as the first-class, I had to change it to `org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter`.

Conclusion:

- You must add the filter and filter-mapping correctly to the web.xml
  of your web application.
- You must run the JVM with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.