# Problems with UTF-8 encoding - web-project

Tags: java, eclipse, web, servlets, wildfly

I'm aware that this question was already asked a couple of times, but I didn't get the problem solved even with the hints mentioned in other posts.
For a small webproject I created some html/jsp pages that are calling links to two servlets. The servlets themselves are talking to a PostgreSQL database. Everything is working instead of the encoding. When I'm typing in special characters (UTF-8) like "ü", "ä" or "ö", I can see them:

- correctly inserted into the web page
- correctly listed inside of the java objects (Debug mode) correctly inserted into the database

Since the web tool reloads the data with every change (a simultaneously work should be provided), I can also see the following steps working:

- after the tool was re-loading the data from the database, the special characters are listed inside of the java objects (Debug mode)
- the attribute inside of the request-object has the correct value

Nevertheless, after reload the data is not shown correctly anymore inside the web page - just cryptic signs.
Can you please support? I already checked the following points:

- encoding of Eclipse
- encoding of database
- encoding of servlets
- encoding of the application server (Wildfly)
- encoding of the JSP files
- encoding inside of Chrome

Best greetings,
Jesfreric

Comment: What is "the web tool" and how does it reload the data?

Comment: The web-tool is the just the name for my "self-written" tool. It just, simply said, offers the possibility to visualize and manipulate data.
The reload is happening via reading the data out of the DB again

Comment: So it is calling a servlet and refreshing the entire page? Or is it using Ajax?

Comment: It is refreshing the whole page. I'm not using Ajax. Only some additional javascript lines

Comment: What's the value of the 'Content-Type' header in the response?

Comment: Perhaps you can post the source code of the offending results page. But try to produce a small page with little source code.

Comment: Hello all. I'm afraid the source code would be too much. But the Content-Type header is in the code: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: The response shows also:
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112030/character-encoding-requestdispatcher